# Can't update Konva rect

Tags: konvajs

I built a grid of rectangles and cached them by calling group.children.cache();

After that on mousemove i have set

```
rect.fillPatternOffsetX(Math.max(newScaleWidth, 0));
rect.fillPatternOffsetY(Math.max(newScaleHeight, 0));
```

and I have called

`layer.draw()`.

without calling `group.clearCache()` I can't see updates.

it's the right way to update Rect?

with `clearCache()` it works on Chrome and Safari, but on Firefox on Mac I have a lot of performance problems.

can someone help me?

Comment: can you share the code..?

Answer (score 0):

this when i create the rects

```
  const rect = new Konva.Rect({
      x: coor.x * this.widthObject,
      y: coor.y * this.heightObject,
      width: this.widthObject,
      height: this.heightObject,
      fillPatternImage: imageObj,
      fillPatternOffsetX: this.scaleWidth,
      fillPatternOffsetY: this.scaleHeight,
      fillPatternScale: {
        x: this.patternScaleX,
        y: this.patternScaleY,
      },
      trick,
  });

    rect.on('click tap', this.handleClickRect);

    this.group.add(rect);

    this.layer.add(this.group);
    this.stage.add(this.layer);
    this.group.children.cache();
```

on mouse move

```
   rects.map((rect) => {
      rect.fillPatternScaleX(Math.min(
        this.patternScaleX,
        this.ratioImageWidthOnRect + incrementScaleRectsX,
      ));
      rect.fillPatternScaleY(Math.min(
        this.patternScaleY,
        this.ratioImageHeightOnRect + incrementScaleRectsY,
      ));
      rect.fillPatternOffsetX(Math.max(newScaleWidth, 0));
      rect.fillPatternOffsetY(Math.max(newScaleHeight, 0));
      return rect;
  });

  // this.group.children.clearCache()
  this.layer.draw();
```

Comment: Have you tried this.layer.batchDraw() instead of draw() function. Check documentation https://konvajs.github.io/docs/performance/Batch_Draw.html

Comment: can you send code in any of online compiler like jsbin or jsfiddle so that we can see the problem that you are facing and help you fix it.